# Prevent map from breaking on motion command error

Tags: vim

The idea is to have a map that allows me to fold blocks of code enclosed in curly braces.

```
nnoremap zff 0f{zf%
```

This works as expected but only on the opening brace.
The following version seems to work as long as { and } are on the same line. Should they be on different lines though the cursor only jumps to the opening { and no fold is created.

```
nnoremap zff 0f{f}zf%
```

---

edit:

The problem appears to be that once there is an error in one of the motion commands the map breaks.
`:silent!` prevents ex commands from breaking a map in case of an error. Is there an equivalent for motion commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that an error in a command sequence breaks the sequence, and this is usually right. If you want to continue even in case of errors, just execute the commands separately through `:normal!`. This can be chained in a single command-line via `:execute`:

```
nnoremap zff :exe 'normal! 0f{' | exe 'normal! f}' | exe 'normal! zf%'
```

Answer (score 3):

Your first mapping should work, unless you have a filetype detection or syntax problem that prevents proper pair-matching.

Your second mapping can't work because `f` (and `FtT`) only works on the current line. Alternatives:

```
f{v/}<CR>zf
f{zf/}<CR>
```

But you can use `zf` with text-objects:

```
zfi{
zfat
zfip
```

so… why bother with a mapping?

Comment: Hello @romainl, thank you for the useful answer (+1). I refined my question out of curiosity, though.